# MySQL writing join on three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have written the following mysql query

```
SELECT distinct name, date
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON (table2.item_id = table1.item_id)
where table1.id IN (SELECT run_id FROM 
table3 where table3.status = 'FAIL') and table1.createdate >= '2011-01-01'
 ;
```

I want to include another field `message` from `table3` in my output.

I guess this might involve joining 3 tables in the query.
Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Your guess is correct. I suggest joining the 3rd table.

Comment: You also need to figure out the common field b/w table 3 and whichever table you join it to(1 or 2) when you add the second join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not quite enough info to fully answer the question. We also want to know:

1. Does the `status` column come from `table1` or from `table3`
2. Can there be more than one `table3` record with a `runid` that matches a `table1.id` value?
3. If there can be, which `table3.message` value do you want to show?

Without knowing that info, all we can do is guess. Here is my guess:

```
SELECT distinct name, date, message
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.item_id = t1.item_id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t1.id =t3.run_id AND t3.status = 'FAIL'
WHERE t1.createdate >= '2011-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct name, date, T3.message
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON (table2.item_id = table1.item_id) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT run_id FROM 
table3 where status = 'FAIL') T3 ON T3.run_id = table1.id
where table1.createdate >= '2011-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.NAME , T1.DATE , T3.MESSAGE
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON
T1.ITEM_ID = T2.ITEM_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3
ON
T1.ID = T3.RUN_ID
WHERE T3.STATUS = 'FAIL' AND T1.CREATEDATE >= '2011-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

select distinct name,date, message from table1 t1,table2 t2,table3 t3 where t1.item_id = t2.item_id and t1.item_id = t3.item_id
and t3.status ='FAIL' AND t1.createdate >= to_date('2011-01-01,'YYYY-DD-MM');